# Why does this sound "wrong"?

Tags: usage

I'm working on a text that includes the following phrase:

> During the previous years he has been working...

Cannot pinpoint exactly which part of it, and why, but somehow it feels wrong to me.

Is there a more comfortable-sounding alternative?

Have thought of: "Over the past few years..." (but what if it's been, say, the last 10 years); "Over previous years..." (but he could no longer be doing it now); "During past years..." (again this possibility of 'once, but no longer'), "During the past few years..." (see the first example).

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The use of the present perfect continuous construction, "*he has been working*", implies an activity that started in the past and continues in the present.

The use of "during the previous years" implies an activity that started in the (more-distant) past and finished in the (less-distant) past, since by specifying "previous" you exclude the current year.

The combination of the two is therefore contradictory, which is probably the source of your discomfort.

Some alternatives:

> For some years now he has been working...
>
> For several years he has been working...
>
> In the last few years he has been working...
>
> In recent years he has been working....

You can adjust these depending on the actual number of years if you need to ("for a few years", "for several years", "for many years", "for the last decade", etc.).

Answer (score 0):

"He has been" and "In the past few years" is redundant.  Either drop the years phrase or add a smaller version of it on to "He has been working", like "He has worked for company X for the last 5 years."  Even better, use a specific year, i.e. "Since 2012 he has worked for company X on project Y"